# Lightning Component Owner

Tags: lightning-aura-components, email

A developer user created a Lightning Component in my sandbox.  The component was moved to production.  The developer's name/email are still associated with the component even though he has never had a user account in production.  This is a problem because his email address appears when the component generates an email to a user.  I need to be able to change the owner of the component.  Thoughts?

Comment: where do you see his email? it might be in apex class from where email goes out because lightning component can't send email itself. can you post your code?

Comment: The owner shouldn't make a difference. Are you sure it's not just a hard-coded email somewhere in the code?

Comment: I have searched everywhere I can think.  The apex controller file doesn't have the email.  I know I created a class to run as an email service.  It shows my email when users get the message & it isn't hardcoded in there.  Applying that logic, I am wondering how it knows to send from my email address on that one & the sandbox developer's name on the one he wrote.

The email that is puzzling sender address looks like:  NIIMBL rajat.jain@mtxb2b.com via 688h2ueu169rxk.6a-tfmfuaq.na50.bnc.salesforce.com

Comment: I did recreate the component & I am still receiving the emails from the developer's name.  Any suggestions of where else to look?  I am very puzzled.

Comment: @SFDCFOX - how does Salesforce know what email address to use when sending email from an apex controller file?  I think that is at the heart of this problem.

Comment: The default address is from the current user's email address, unless you specify otherwise (setOrgWideEmailAddressId). Unfortunately, I think we would need to see the code involve to know for sure. The only time the "code owner" email address means anything is for Apex Code Exception Emails.

Comment: This apex code is being triggered when a form is submitted by an unauthenticated user.  What does Salesforce do in a situation like that?  I added an organization wide email and I did not see a change in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating an OWD in Salesforce & then setting the mail OWD setting in my controller code.  Thank you for the help!